# Getting the nrow() of 3 matrices simultaneously in R?

Tags: r, function, matrix, vectorization

Suppose I have the following 3 matrices:

```
p.b7.4 = matrix(1:4, nrow = 2) 
p.b6.4 = matrix(1:6, nrow = 3) 
p.b5.4 = matrix(1:8, nrow = 4)
```

If I (further) vectorize `nrow()` in R:

```
vec.nrow = Vectorize(function(x) nrow(x), "x")
```

Is it then possible to ***get the number of rows for the 3 matrices above simultaneously?***

I tried the following without success:

```
vec.nrow(noquote(paste0("p.b", 7:5, rep(".", 3), rep(4, 3))))
```

Comment: If `nrow1 <- Vectorize(function(x) nrow(x))`, then `nrow1(mget(ls(pattern = 'p.b')))` should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mget` to put all matrices in a list and then use `lapply` (also try `sapply`) to loop through them to obtain `NROW`

```
lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "p.b")), NROW)
$p.b5.4
[1] 4

$p.b6.4
[1] 3

$p.b7.4
[1] 2
```